# Get Result of ICalculator without actually populating a field (ArcObjects)

Tags: arcobjects

I have two feature classes: FeatureClassA and FeatureClassB.  I am running a cursor on FeatureClassA and I have some logic statements (spatial and attribute logic) that compares the current feature in FeatureClassA to FeatureClassB and returns one matching record in FeatureClassB.  I want to then do a field calculation on a field in FeatureClassA using the fields in the returned record from FeatureClassB.

To achieve this, I have the user build a field calculator expression using the ICalculatorUI2 interface.  This dialog is familiar to ArcGIS users.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ICalculatorUI2 calcUI = new CalculatorUIClass();
    calcUI.Table = FeatureClassB as ITable;
    calcUI.DoModal(ArcMap.Application.hWnd);
    string expression = calcUI.Expression;
    calcUI = null;
}
```

If I wanted to calculate a field in FeatureClassB, I could just use ICalculator.

```
ICalculator calculator = new Calculator();
calculator.Expression = calc.Expression;
calculator.Field = "MyField";
calculator.Cursor = calcUI.Table.Search(null, false);
calculator.Calculate();
```

The problem is, I don't want to actually calculate a field in FeatureClassB.  I want the result of the field calculation to put into a field in FeatureClassA.  Is there anyway to get the result of the field calculation?

Comment: Why not do it in an edit operation and then undo? Or copy the feature class to *in memory* and then it will disappear when the program finishes.